# Pagination: How to limit number of pages on small screen devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, sass

I will have some pages and I have to apply pagination to them.

**on small device (show only 2 page numbers)**:-

```
<<  <  1 | 2  >  >>
```

**on medium and above devices (show all page numbers)**:

```
<<  <  1 | 2 | 3 | 4  >  >>
```

I am able to show all the page numbers on medium to large screens but the requirement is to show only 2 page numbers, at a time, on small screen devices. Please advice how to handle this responsive design, how to hide other numbers and show only 2 at a time on small screens?

https://jsfiddle.net/3rvm34a7/

Comment: I hope my javascript code worked for you. If so, please mark my answer as a correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/what-is-the-best-treatment-of-pagination-block-in-mobile-view

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to implement this :

**1. Service side :**

You can detect the HTTP user agent from server if you are using php or python etc. Accordingly you can send pagination html to the view.

**2. Client side :**

a) 
 You can detect the device width or device agent from javascript. Then you hide the larger pagination if device is smaller and vice versa.
Link : [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

b) Using Css : 
 You can apply class to link of pages 3,4. Use media query to hide these pages on smaller resolutions using simple css. However when i click on a page, make sure you update the page classes accoedingly and dynamically update the pagination HTML.
Link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS solution for hiding the pages on smaller devices
and showing them for larger devices [`JSfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/3rvm34a7/2/).
It will also showing and hiding other pages when rotating the tablet / phone to landscape.
You can resize fiddle window to see how it works.

Comment: Not suitable for dynamic websites

Comment: This is just `CSS` solution. You will add `span` element with `css` class with php or any other language is used to get pagination, with `if / else` according to current page

Answer (score 0):

**I updated your jsfiddle here:** https://jsfiddle.net/3rvm34a7/1/

I added a "pg" class name to your list page numbers and added the following code.

```
if(screen.width < 500){
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("pg");
  for(var i = 2; i < list.length; i++){
     list[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```